# Response to REST client from Camel CXFRS route?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to create a response to a REST web service call in a CXFRS Camel route, but no matter what I do the response to the client is always the same 200, not 201. Here's my route:

```
<route id="front-end">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:myService" />
    <setBody>
        <constant>Will do...</constant>
    </setBody>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpResponseCode">
        <constant>201</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
        <constant>more/blah</constant>
    </setHeader>
</route>
```

The body is returned but the response code and content type are ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Which version of camel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Camel 2.13.1 and CXF 2.7.11 with Spring 3.2.8-RELEASE

Comment: I just update to Camel 2.14.0 and CXF 3.0.1 but this does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically camel-cxfrs overwrites any headers set in exchange when it converts the exchange to actual HTTP response 
See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-cxf/2.7.0/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/jaxrs/CxfRsProducer.java#163):

```
exchange.getOut().setHeaders(binding.bindResponseHeadersToCamelHeaders(response, exchange));
```

And this happens because [DefaultCxfRsBinding](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-cxf/2.7.0/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/jaxrs/DefaultCxfRsBinding.java#DefaultCxfRsBinding.bindResponseHeadersToCamelHeaders%28java.lang.Object%2Corg.apache.camel.Exchange%29) expects a jaxrs Response as a parameter.

So to fix the issue you either override DefaultCxfRsBinding with custom one in order to copy headers from exchange.getIn().

```
    <cxf:rsServer id="MyService" address="/myAddress">      
    <cxf:binding><bean class="MyCustomCxfRsBinding" /></cxf:binding>                
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myResourceWithJSR311Annotations" />
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
    </cxf:rsServer>
```

Or make your camel route to return a jaxrs Response **with headers** instead of setting headers in the rout or in camel processors. Something

```
class HttpHeaderProcessor implements Processor
{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
    {
        Message message = exchange.getIn();
        Response response = convertToJaxRs(message);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("Test", "Won't work unless DefaultCxfRsBinding is not replaced with a custom one");

    }

    private Response convertToJaxRs(Message message)
    {
        ResponseBuilder jaxrsResponseBuilder = Response.ok(message.getBody(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        jaxrsResponseBuilder.header("header1", "you'll see this");
        Response response = jaxrsResponseBuilder.build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

For your sample:

```
<route id="front-end">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:myService" />
    <setBody>
        set it to Response.ok(your message).header(x, y).build()
    </setBody>
```

You can also use a Service bean returning a jaxrs.Response with headders

```
<route id="front-end">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:myService" />
    <bean ref="myServiceImpl">
```

Comment: This is great feedback, thank you very much. I ended up creating a custom processor, similar to your solution, and it allowed me to move forward. However, it felt like a hack so I switched track a bit to use REST DSL (Camel 2.14) with the Servlet component, which feels more flexible to me.