# Camel loosing HTTP headers on response to original caller

Tags: java, routes, http-headers, apache-camel, esb

I've created a route to allow me to forward a REST call. Everything is going well, except I cannot modify the HTTP headers of the response (actually I can't even get them untouched on the response).

```java
// My processor
private void remplacerLiensDansHeader(final Exchange exchange, final String rootUrlPivotJoram, final String rootUrlRemplacement) {
    // That is OK, I get the values just fine
    ArrayList<String> oldLinks = exchange.getIn().getHeader(HEADER_LINK, ArrayList.class);

    // This is also OK
    final List<String> newLinks = anciensLiens.stream().map(lien -> lien.replace(rootUrlPivotJoram, rootUrlRemplacement)).collect(toList());

    // No error, but apparently doesn't work
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader(HEADER_LINK, newLinks);
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader("test", "test");
}

// Route configuration
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    this.from(RestRouteBuilder.endPoint(createProducerJoramConfiguration))
        .setExchangePattern(InOut)
        .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI)
        .toD(createProducerJoramConfiguration.getUrlDestination())
        .setHeader("test", () -> "test") // that doesn't work either
        .process(createProducerJoramConfiguration.getProcessor()); // this is the processor with the code above
}
```

This is the response I get (note that the response code is `200` and I think it's weird as the original is `201`)

```sh
curl -v -XPost --user "xxx:yyyy" http://localhost:10015/zzzz/webservices/xxxxx
```

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 10015 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'xxx'
> Post /zzzzz/webservices/eeee HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:10015
> Authorization: Basic pppppppppppppppppp==
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 11:17:49 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Two things I've noticed:

- if I add a body in the processor, then the body is present in the response,
- if I remove the processor, the headers present in the "original response" are not present either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was the cxfrs component.

We manage to find an answer here : see : [Response to REST client from Camel CXFRS route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923811/response-to-rest-client-from-camel-cxfrs-route)

Here is the final solution.

Thanks to everyone that looked or answer, I hope that'll help someone else.

```
public class ModificationHeaderLinkProcessor implements Processor {

  private static final String HEADER_LINK = "Link";

  @Override
  public void process(final Exchange exchange) {
    List<String> newLinks= getNewLinks(exchange, oldUrl, newUrl);
    ResponseBuilder builder = createHttpResponse(exchange);
    builder.header(HEADER_LINK, newLinks);
    exchange.getIn().setBody(builder.build());
  }

  private List<String> getNewLinks(final Exchange exchange, final String oldUrl, final String newUrl) {
    ArrayList<String> oldLinks= exchange.getIn().getHeader(HEADER_LINK, ArrayList.class);
    return oldLinks.stream().map(link-> link.replace(oldUrl, newUrl)).collect(toList());
  }

  private ResponseBuilder createHttpResponse(final Exchange exchange) {
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(getHttpStatusCode(exchange))
                                      .entity(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    clearUselessHeader(exchange);
    exchange.getIn().getHeaders().forEach(builder::header);
    return builder;
  }

  private void clearUselessHeader(final Exchange exchange) {
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader(HEADER_LINK);
    exchange.getIn().removeHeaders("Camel*");
  }

  private Integer getHttpStatusCode(final Exchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getIn().getHeader(exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
  }

  private final String getPropertiesValue(CamelContext camelContext, String key) {
    return camelContext.getPropertiesComponent().resolveProperty(key).orElseThrow();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what headers you exactly lose, but be aware that the [Camel HTTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html) has a **default header filter** (as lots of Camel components have).

If you don't specify your own [HeaderFilterStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/80b92e3624ae5db59a1a24a441f1b10b39eaa1a5/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/HeaderFilterStrategy.java), the default [HttpHeaderFilterStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/80b92e3624ae5db59a1a24a441f1b10b39eaa1a5/components/camel-http-common/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/http/common/HttpHeaderFilterStrategy.java) is used.

This default filters the following headers:

- content-length
- content-type
- host
- cache-control
- connection
- date
- pragma
- trailer
- transfer-encoding
- upgrade
- via
- warning
- Camel*
- org.apache.camel*

With this filter, Camel wants to avoid that old HTTP headers are still present on outgoing requests (probably with wrong data).

The filtering of Camel headers is just to remove Camel specific stuff that is not relevant for HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for answering unforunately I was loosing a custom header that add nothing to do with one of the above.